# How do I add tags to cloud logging? For example, GET, POST

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, winston, bunyan

I'm the web developer. I'm currently using the Google Cloud platform. Deploy the next.js(node.js) application through Google Cloud Run. Use the Google Cloud platform throughout your company's product. I have a question to ask you.
How do I add tags to cloud logging? For example, http method type or another application log's contents(user-agent's device, http status code, category, type, etc..) like (below)createPractice, fs7a3hdhwh6c.)
I'm leaving my Next.js application log in cloud logging, and I want to show the severity of that log as tag (button shape). What should I do?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmoXL.png)

Comment: I didn't catch want you want to achieve. Do you want to put the HTTP verb (GET, POST) in the "blue bubble" at the beginning of the log line, like createPractice?

Answer (score 0):

You can add log field to summary line like this.

[image]

However, you can't add custom/calculated field in the summary line